# How to draw a jagged line?

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

How can you draw a jagged line in matlab? The graph will be like a saw, the slope is same but peaks are different.

For example:

```
Peak #   Start        End
1        (0.2,2.2)    (1.5,0)
2        (1.5,3)      (3.27,0)
3        (3.27,1.2)   (3.98,0)
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `plot` with the x and y coordinates of your points:

```
x = [0.2 1.5 1.5 3.27 3.27 3.98];
y = [2.2 0 3 0 1.2 0];
plot(x, y)
```

Unless you don't want the vertical lines? You can do it like this:

```
x = [0.2 1.5 nan 1.5 3.27 nan 3.27 3.98];
y = [2.2 0 nan 3 0 nan 1.2 0];
plot(x, y)
```